# Form based authentication for anonymous site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have some application pages and I have to assign the form based authentication for some pages as this site is anonymous.
Is it possible with custom development?